# Select a dataframe using boolean selection, and then extract the value corresponding to a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, boolean-expression

Example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-3, -2, 0], 'b': [-2, 2, 5], 'c': [-1, 0, 7], 'd': [1, 4, 8]})
```

I'm trying to do something which I would expect to be fairly simple, and which is indeed immediate in other languages supporting the dataframe class, such as R. I just want to extract a single value from `df`, with the only caveat that I select the row with a boolean expression (say, `"a"==0), instead than by using a label. The column instead is selected by label, as usual. For example, this works, but it seems unnecessarily wasteful:

```
df["c"][df["a"]==0][1]
```

Rather than directly extracting a value from a dataframe, this instruction 1) extracts a Pandas Series, 2) selects a row in the series and 3) selects the second element of the array returned by the row selection! (the first element is the index). Not only does it seem needlessly complicated, but I'm worried it could also be slow for very large dataframes.

I tried other solutions using `.at` or `.iat` but nothing seems to work. Isn't there a simpler/smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in one shot:

```
In [11]: df.loc[df["a"]==0, "c"]
Out[11]:
2    7
Name: c, dtype: int64

In [12]: df.loc[df["a"]==0, "c"].iat[0]
Out[12]: 7
```

Comment: can you explain why it works? If  `df.loc[df["a"]==0, "c"]` returns the array `(2, 7)`, then I would expect `7` to be the _second_ element of the array, not the first. Is this because `df.loc[df["a"]==0, "c"]` doesn't return an array, but a Series, thus `.iat[0]` simply selects the first element of the Series?

Answer (score 1):

Using `nonzero` with `iat`

```
df.iat[(df.a==0).nonzero()[0][0],2]
Out[114]: 7
```

Comment: ?? I don't understand, what did you do? Doesn't `.iat` accept only integer (not boolean) indices?

Comment: @DeltaIV check what nonzero did https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nonzero.html